# Не работает средство разработчика в ie 11

Tags: internet-explorer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой ? Отказывается работать средство разработчика в ie 11 (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно скачать и установить обновление от Windows 7 (KB3008923) и перезагрузить компьютер.

Скачать можно, например, [с официального сайта](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45134).

Comment: Вам помогло? Почему вы решили, что подразумевается Windows 7?

Comment: спасибо, уже давно решил ) просто обновил ie с офф сайта

Comment: @0xdb да, помогло, т.к. точно такая же ошибка была. Почему Windows 7? тут пару причин: на Windows 7 - это последняя версия IE (с учетом 2017/2018 года). Во-вторых, (из личного опыта), IE11 также есть у тех, у кого Windows 8(8.1), но (в большей части) у кого были 8(8.1) предпочли Windows 10 (где уже стоит Edge). Но опять же сугубо ИМХО.
Ответ оставил тут для того, чтобы если у кого-то была аналогичная проблема - смог бы найти тут овтет

Comment: спасибо большое, ваша статья помогла мне, вы чертовы гении))))